# Why is not primary index here?

Tags: mysql

Recently,I have reviwed the basic of SQL and found A question about index.
My Working environment is as follows:

- os: Centos 7
- mysql: 5.7.39
- database: sakila
- table: customer
  AND My question is why Innodb uses `idx_fk_store_id` instead of the primary index when I use `select count(customer_id) from customer`

```
mysql> explain select count(customer_id) from customer;
```

AND Result:

| type | key | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- |
| index | idx_fk_store_id | Using index |

The code to create this table is as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE `customer`(
`customer_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`store_id`   tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(`customer_id`),
KEY `idx_fk_store_id`(`store_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDE AUTO_INCREMENT=600 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

I've considered that it caused by MYSQL's Optimizer , even if it's hard to understand.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the result of `EXPLAIN` and the `CREATE TABLE` statement as code block, not as images.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `type: index` in the EXPLAIN report indicates it is doing an index-scan. That is, reading every entry in the index `idk_fk_store_id`.

It can get the values of the primary key from a secondary index, so it can count them.

The alternative of using the primary key would be a table-scan, which reads every row of the table.

The primary key index in InnoDB is the *clustered index*. It stores all the columns of the table.

The secondary index stores only the values of `store_id` plus the primary key values of rows where a given store_id value occurs.

So it will be able to get the same answer by doing an index-scan, by reading fewer pages than doing the table-scan.

Answer (score 0):

Saying `COUNT(x)` is common mistake.

- `COUNT(*)` counts the number of *rows*
- `COUNT(x)` counts the number of rows *where `x` is `NOT NULL`*

So, if you try `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM customer`, the Explain will again say that it is using that index.  But for a different reason than Bill gave.  This time the Optimizer's logic goes this way:

1. find the "smallest" index.  That will happen to be the same `store_id` index.
2. count the "rows" in that index.  But no need to test whether `customer_id IS NOT NULL`.

Another note:  In MySQL, the `PRIMARY KEY` is required to be `NOT NULL`, so `customer_id` cannot be `NULL`.  Also you declared it to be `NOT NULL`.  Hence `COUNT(customer_id)` is necessarily the same as `COUNT(*)`.

TMI.